# Look for a unique value using two variables

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need to implement the `ISSUES` column by using `REFERENCE` and `LOCALISATION` variables for each rows with unique values stocked on `Table_issues_Localisation`.

The problem is, those two variables make a two dimension table, so I have to dynamically select the right column of `LOCALISATION`.

Here is an explanation of what I need to do with an image. I'm sorry for posting an image but I think this is way more understandable.

[image: Explanation]

I tried to make a query to update row by row the `Table_Observation.ISSUES` column with informations stocked on variable columns (=SELECT(SELECT))) of `Table_issues_Localisation`.

On `Table_Observation.ROW_NUMBER` column indicates the number of each rows. It is used for the loop.

```
DO $$

DECLARE
my_variable TEXT;

BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..35 LOOP 

    my_variable = SELECT((SELECT LOCALISATION FROM Table_Observation WHERE Table_Observation.ROW_NUMBER = i) FROM Table__issues_Localisation ON Table_Observation.REFERENCE = Table__issues_Localisation.REFERENCE)

    UPDATE Table_Observation 
    SET ISSUES = my_variable
    WHERE Table_Observation.ROW_NUMBER = i

  END LOOP;
END; 
$$
```

Postgres v 9.4

I hope I'm clear enough,

Comment: No, you are not clear at all. Start by explaining your actual task, not parts of your idea for a solution. Always provide our Postgres version and basic table definitions. Chances are, all you need is a plain `UPDATE` command. No loops, no variables, no plpgsql.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: I think there is a rather large [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. You have become fixated on the need for a `FOR` loop, but your actual problem has nothing to do with that loop; it's that you need to pick a dynamic column from a table based on a variable. One solution is to "pivot" the columns of `Table_issues_Localisation` into rows, so that you can access the different "localisations". Once you've pivoted them, you don't need the loop, just a normal `JOIN`.

Comment: I could make it this way but i've got 80000+ references in different tables and only 100 localisations. Furthermore, localisations are manually implemented. For these two reasons I think this is more ergonomic to stay this way.
One more reason is that if I pivot the table, there will still be two variables to check, one on x the other on y. The problem will still be here.

Comment: @p.volte The point is, the for loop isn't your problem, the *dnyamic column selection* is. Even if you had only one row, you need to decide which column to take the `LOCALISATION` value from. You could pivot the whole table, use a `CASE` statement, or a number of other approaches. But do it with one row first, and worry about the loop or set operation later.

Comment: @IMSoP The dynamic column select is the problem. But if I pivot the table `LOCALISATION`, `REFERENCE` rows would be in columns, then the problem stays the same : i have to dynamically select those `REFERENCES` instead of dynamically select `issues`. I actually have two dynamic variable to check : one on rows `REFERENCES`, the other on columns `issues_*`. If I pivot the table nothing will change.

Comment: Fine, I conceded, a full pivot might not be your solution. But **your problem has nothing to do with for loops and variables**, so you should reframe your question around the actual problem, which will make it simpler for other people to understand, and indeed easier for you to think about.

Comment: how many issues-columns does table_issues_localisation have?

Comment: @IMSoP You're right, this was not well explained. I edited my post so it can be clearer.

Comment: @joop It will increase but actually it has 45 issues-columns.

Comment: Dynamic sql seems to be the answer, then. (loop over the column-names := Localisation and generate an update-statement for each one) Or just duplicate and search_and_replace manually, which is probably faster, for an incidental task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need PL/pgSQL or a loop for this. You can do that with a single update statement:

```
update observation o
   set issues = row_to_json(il) ->> o.localisation
from issues_localisation  il
where il.reference = o.reference;
```

This requires that the values in `observation.localisation` exactly map to the column names in issues_localisation.

With the following test data:

```
create table observation 
(
   rn integer primary key, 
   reference integer, 
   localisation text, 
   issues text
);

create table issues_localisation 
(
  reference integer, 
  issues_12 text, 
  issues_17 text, 
  issues_27 text, 
  issues_34 text
);

insert into observation (rn, reference, localisation)
values
  (1, 27568, 'issues_27'),
  (2, 6492, 'issues_34'),
  (3, 1529, 'issues_34'),
  (4, 1529, 'issues_34'),
  (5, 709, 'issues_12');

insert into issues_localisation (reference, issues_12, issues_17, issues_27, issues_34)
values
    (29, 'FB', 'FB', 'TFB', null),
   (506, 'M', null,  'M', null),
   (709, 'TF', null, null, null),
  (1234, null, 'TF', 'TF', null),
  (1529, 'FB', 'FB', 'FB', 'M'),
  (3548, null, 'M', null, null),
  (6492, 'FB', 'FB', 'FB', null),
 (18210, 'TFB', null, 'TFB', 'TFB'),
 (27568, 'TF', null, 'TF', 'TF');
```

The update will result in this data in the table observation:

```
rn | reference | localisation | issues
---+-----------+--------------+-------
 1 |     27568 | issues_27    | TF    
 2 |      6492 | issues_34    |       
 3 |      1529 | issues_34    | M     
 4 |      1529 | issues_34    | M     
 5 |       709 | issues_12    | TF
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/OCGFM81609

---

For your next question you should supply the sample data (and the expected output) the way I did in my answer.

I removed the completely useless prefix `table_` from the table names as well. That is [horrible naming convention](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/154251/1822).

Comment: Note: you could even use dynamic sql to generate the CASE-expression! Profit!!!1!!!

Comment: @joop: you don't actually need dynamic SQL for this. A little JSON magic will do. See my new UPDATE statement

Comment: Well, that looks lime an elegant little hack.

Comment: It works! This script is so perfect! Thank you for your patience, I will do my best to formulate my questions next time :)

Answer (score 1):

And here is an (unfinished, still need to execute) example of dynamic sql:

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION bagger (_name text) RETURNS text
AS
$func$
DECLARE upd text;
BEGIN

upd := format('
        UPDATE observation dst
        SET issues = src.%I
        FROM issues_localisation src
        WHERE src.reference = dst.reference
        AND dst.localisation = %L
         ;', _name, _name);

-- RAISE NOTICE upd;
RETURN upd;
END
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
        ;

-- SELECT bagger('issues_12' );
WITH loc AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT localisation AS loc
        FROM observation
        )
SELECT bagger( loc.loc)
FROM loc
        ;
```